# Why opening access table took around 2 minutes?

Tags: c#, ms-access, strongly-typed-dataset

I have an Access database which has a table with around 6k records. When I am trying to open it in C# using dataset method, it took around 2 minutes to open. Why is this happening and how can speed it up?

```
MyDataSet _dataSet = new MyDataSet();
MyDataTableAdapter _myDataTableAdapter = new MyDataTableAdapter();
_myDataTableAdapter.GetData();
```

Last line tooks a long time (around 2 minutes) to get the data.

I created a strongly type dataset using VS tools (See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04y282hb(v=vs.80).aspx).

Then I used the above code to retrieve data out of database. I know that Access is very slow but for 6K record, it should take such amount of time.

The database is local and next to application.

Comment: You should always post the code in question.

Comment: Convert it to a *real* DBMS. That should help ;)

Comment: @Steve: my first thought, "because it is Access" ... :)  seriously, though, it shouldn't be taking that long for 6k records.

Comment: @user: you really need to show us a little more than this. We don't know what your `SELECT` statement looks like; is your .mdb file local to your development?

Comment: @Abstract, ya, I was just trying to be funny :) agreed it shouldnt take that long.

Comment: 6000 records is small even for MS-Access, so unless you've done something screwy in your select statement (e.g. cartesian product), or the database is remote and the bandwidth is too restricted, or the code is executing on an overburdened shared server, or the table contains large amounts of binary data, the records should be returned almost instantaneously.

Comment: Problem solved: Thanks to Tim for his comment: “the table contains large amounts of binary data”

I checked the size of database and it was 64MByte! I checked all tables and there is not any large binary data so there should be some other reasons for database to be such big, so I tried to compress it and now its size is 6Mbyte (reasonable!) and code returns data instantly.

Comment: Access is not slow, and it's a proper RDBMS. Comments to the effect that either of these are true just reflect the ignorance (or incompetence) of those making them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: Thanks to Tim for his comment: “the table contains large amounts of binary data” I checked the size of database and it was 64MByte! I checked all tables and there is not any large binary data so there should be some other reasons for database to be such big, so I tried to compress it and now its size is 6Mbyte (reasonable!) and code returns data instantly.